# Single Magento eCommerce store with 40 branches

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have a store which has 40 branches over the country. I need to setup a Magento eCommerce site for my stores to sell different products.

1. Need to show all products from all branches (approx 40 branches).
2. When user selects a product to buy, need to show the branches where selected products are available.
3. After branch selection, proceed to payment and shipping details.
4. Each branch needs its own inventory and administration.
5. Needs to list products in Amazon and Ebay.

Is it possible to setup the above requirements using Magento (with or without using multistore concept)?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you defined, you would like to have solution without multistore, then I recommend to use custom ecommerce solution, e.g. elite ecommerce solution by eDigitalFields will help you to customize everything starting from the process of inventory, shopping cart, shipping, checkout and order management. They have the solutions exactly you are looking for.
Hope an attached illustration and your problem matches together and this solution work fine for you.

Learn more about this Multi Store Ecommerce Solution [here](http://www.edigitalfields.com/multi-store-ecommerce-solution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Except of number one you can do this pretty simple by using separate store views for each branch.

To show products form all store views you have to code your own module.